# Is every dg-coalgebra the colimit of its finite dimensional dg-subcoalgebras?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, model-categories, coalgebras, dg-categories

I saw this result in [*A Model Category Structure for Differential Graded Coalgebras*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/GetzlerGoerss99.pdf) by Getzler-Goerss, but when the coalgebra is non-negatively graded, is this property also satisfied when the dg coalgebra is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded?.

Thanks.

Comment: The result the OP is pointing to in Getzler-Goerss is Corollary 1.6.

Comment: @david Indeed, and I also expect to extend this proposition to differential $\mathbb{Z}$-graded coalgebras by using the previous lemmas of the article. I hope an artifice might suffice.

Answer (score 6):

For coassociative dg-coalgebras over any field $k$ the answer is positive, because:

1. Let $C$ be a $\mathbb Z$-graded coalgebra and $D\subset C$ a finite-dimensional ungraded subcoalgebra (of the underlying ungraded coalgebra) of $C$.  Let $D^{gr}\subset C$ denote the graded vector subspace spanned by all the grading components of the elements of $D$.  Then $D\subset D^{gr}$ and $D^{gr}$ is a finite-dimensional graded subcoalgebra of $C$.
2. Let $(C,d)$ be a dg-coalgebra and $D\subset C$ be a finite-dimensional graded subcoalgebra of $C$.  Set $D^{dg}=D+d(D)\subset C$.  Then $D\subset D^{dg}$ and $D^{dg}$ is a finite-dimensional dg-subcoalgebra of $C$.

Using the observations 1. and 2. and the fact that any ungraded coassociative coalgebra is the union of its finite-dimensional subcoalgebras, one deduces the assertion that any $\mathbb Z$-graded dg-coalgebra is the union of its finite-dimensional dg-subcoalgebras.

Possible generalizations: One can replace a field $k$ by a Noetherian commutative ring $k$ and speak about subcoalgebras that are finitely generated as $k$-modules (instead of "finite-dimensional").  All the assertions remain true.

EDIT: I've realized that the preceding paragraph is problematic for the following reason: given a $k$-submodule $D$ is a $k$-module $C$, the tensor product $D\otimes_k D$ is not a submodule of the tensor product $C\otimes_k C$, generally speaking.  So the very notion of a $k$-subcoalgebra for a commutative ring $k$ is problematic, or at least requires extra care with nonexact tensor products.  So, I retract the preceding paragraph.

One cannot drop the coassociativity condition.  Indeed, even for ungraded coalgebras over a field of characteristic $0$, there is an example of infinite-dimensional Lie coalgebra $L$ having no nonzero finite-dimensional subcoalgebras.  The Lie coalgebra $L$ is simplest described in terms of its dual topological Lie algebra structure (on a pro-finite-dimensional topological vector space): $L^*=\mathfrak g=k[[z]]\,d/dz$, the Lie algebra of vector fields on the formal disk.

Comment: Thank you!. Apparently you did not need $C$ to be counital, did you?.

Comment: No, counitality is not necessary.  However, there is a problem with the next-to-last paragraph of my answer.  I am now adding an edit.

Comment: Concerning counitality, it is of course not needed in 1. and 2., but the key question is extending to noncounital coassociative ungraded coalgebras $C$ the standard result that coassociative coalgebras are unions of their finite-dimensional subcoalgebras.  The standard arguments that I know are using counitality, but it can be avoided.  Alternatively, you can adjoint a counit to $C$ formally, passing from $C$ to the counital coalgebra $C'=k\oplus C$, represent $C'$ as the union of its finite-dimensional subcoalgebras $D'$, and conclude that $C=C'/k$ is the union of $D=D'\bmod k$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I apologize for my delay in aswering, I tried to better understand your edit. With this result in hand, is it reasonable to conclude that the category of dg coalgebras has all (small) limits?. I mean, by applying dualization on the finite dimensional dg subcoalgebras and assuming the existence of all small colimits in the category of dg algebras.

Comment: The assertion is correct: all small limits exist in the category of dg-coalgebras.  I do not immediately see how this follows from all dg-coalgebras being unions of their finite-dimensional subcoalgebras.  Maybe one can deduce the former from the latter by proving that the category of dg-coalgebras is locally presentable (locally finitely presentable, in fact).

Comment: I see, this assertion is proposition 1.8 in the article by Getzler and Goerss and is proved by using a strange a strange category to me named the category of **profinite ** differential graded algebras, can you please tell me a more direct argument to deduce such a result?.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The category of $\mathbb{Z}$-coalgebras is locally presentable, and objects are filtered colimits of finite dimensional subobjects. See the appendix to [Coalgebraic models for combinatorial model categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5303) by Ching and Riehl. See also Lemma 5.2 of [Model Structures for Coalgebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5526.pdf) by Drummond-Cole and Hirsh. [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397503003785) of Adamek and Porst might also be helpful.

By the way, the main result of the Getzler-Goerss paper you cite is generalized in Corollary 6.3.5 of [A necessary and sufficient condition for induced model structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.08154) by Hess, Kedziorek, Riehl, and Shipley. It works for any $\mathbb{Z}$-graded coalgebras over any commutative ring $R$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check the references.

Comment: @VictorTC As an additional remark, this is true more in general for coalgebras over cooperads, see Lemmas 4, 5, and Proposition 12 of the article *Homotopy theory of unital algebras* by B. Le Grignou.

Comment: N.B., we work explicitly with *conilpotent* coalgebras, and I do not know how to extend our method for proving presentability to the full category of coalgebras. So our paper may not be particularly useful for you.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud do you know how to resolve the seeming discrepancy between Lemma 5 of Le Grignou and Leonid's counterexample below?

Comment: @Gabriel sorry, I forgot to mention that in Brice's article the coalgebras are supposed to be conilpotent (as can be gathered from the start of the proof of Lemma 5). I suppose Leonid's example is non-conilpotent.